# How to get current logged in user (Windows) from Nodejs app

Tags: node.js, windows, local-system-account

I'm writing a Nodejs application running in client machine (Windows 10), it uses the current logged in user to authenticate on the server.

The problem is, if I run this application under the SYSTEM account then I couldn't get the current logged in user to authenticate.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: how are you executing your application?

Comment: Logged in to windows by user A (normal user), then right-click on .exe file and choose "Run as administrator", then enter the password of user B (administrator account), then the application always return B

Comment: Our customer run the application under a policy (use SYSTEM account the run the application process), so that it always use SYSTEM account to authenticate in server rather than the current logged in user

Comment: Maybe you should update the questin with these details too ;-)

Comment: @JoSSte: thanks for your recommendation, I hope people will read our comments :)

Comment: have you read https://superuser.com/questions/1092595/how-do-i-get-current-logged-in-user-name-when-running-a-batch-file-as-administra and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439932/getting-currently-logged-on-user-when-running-as-admin ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187556/discussion-between-phuc-and-josste).

Comment: We can do that, I just cannot chat from this network...

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved it by using:

```
 exec('for /f "tokens=2" %u in ('query session ^| findstr /R "^>"') do @echo %u',
 function (error, stdout, stderr) {
     username = stdout.trim()
 });
```